# Node.js External function calling

Tags: javascript, node.js, web

So I've been using NodeJS but I have a heavy background on C and C++, and I would like to know how would I "simulate" the header effect on NodeJS.

I have the following code

**foo.js**

```
 var Discord = require("discord.js");
    var request = require('request');
    var http = require('http');
    var express = require('express');
    var util = require('./dead.js');

util.beef()
```

then inside the other .js file

**dead.js**

```
exports.module = {
beef: function(){ request(something) }
}
```

I'm trying to make use of the request variable before declared inside foo.js, but it won't work because Node says it doesn't exist (so, ok it went out of scope)

1. Do I have to `require` every file I want to use in dead.js?
2. Would using `require` impact the performance too much?
3. When is it preferable to have a long
   single js file rather than have multiple ones and `require` in each
   one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `require()` every file every time you use it.

You cannot share variables directly across files, and this is a good thing (it prevents conflicts).

`require()` caches everything, so there are no performance concerns.

You should not put everything in a single giant JS file; that would be hard to maintain.